# Accessing Datarepeater Button

Tags: vb.net

I have added a button in datarepeater.  If clicked once, it executes code and Button.text should change to Yes.  Clicked again, it executes the opposite code and button.text should change to No.  Codes are being executed (I am using flag variable) but Button.text is not changing.

How to change this text.  I am simply trying Button.text="Yes"  but probably I need to give some reference of the row no. too.  How to do it?

Please advise.
Thanks
Furqan

Answer (score 0):

Please check this question: 
[Handle Button Click in WinForm DataRepeater C# Power Pack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1483323/handle-button-click-in-winform-datarepeater-c-power-pack)

Also: the CurrentItem property has a property named Controls that allows you to access its child controls like this: CurrentItem.Controls["OKButton"]

Comment: Thanks, it gives item index but does not server my purpose.  For example it gives 1 for all Close Buttons, in any rows

Comment: Could you show us your code? See also my addition to my answer.